# How to write multiple cmd prompt commands in one single batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need four command prompt commands to run in one batch file. It should run from top to bottom. The commands are:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
exit
```

Comment: just add it in line in a file and run the shell script file.

Answer (score 10):

To perform commands in a batch file, first of all start it with `@echo off` then put your first command, then second.... and then you can end it with `exit` (Though it isn't 100% neccesary)

```
@echo off    
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
exit /b
```

To save this as a batch file do the following:

1. Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type in `notepad`
3. Press enter (or click OK)
4. Type the above script into the text editor (or copy & paste it)
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or click `File > save`)
6. In the `Save as type:` list, select `All files (*.*)`
7. Give your batch file a name and end it with `.bat`
8. Click on `Save` or press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

And that's it, your batch file will now perform the specified commands when it's launched

Comment: 5a. be sure to change the coding to ANSI.

Comment: @Stephan Notepad defaults to ANSI every time the save dialog opens, but I take your point

Comment: well, it didn't on *my* windows - until I changed it once. Since then, it also defaults to ANSI.

Answer (score -1):

You mean four commands to run from one batch file. Actually that's what batch files are for!

1.Open Notepad or any text editor.
2.Type each command on a separate line, in the order you want.
3. Save the file as firstBatch.bat
4. Close your text editor.

When you run that batch file (I hope you know how), they will all run as you want.

Comment: I have tried and only first command is executed not the second one. How I can execute the the both commands?

Comment: Is the first command one that finishes? Or is it still running? If you run it from the command line does it go back to the prompt?

Comment: First command finish its execution and the next one do not executes.